# How to allow only numbers as input in Javascript , why doesn't my code work?

Tags: javascript

I want write a function to prevent any input other than numbers 0-9 and the return key so the user can make corrections. I know that this type of question have been asked several times but why doesn't my code work. Does it has to do with the shift key? Why am I getting "event is not defined"?

In the snippet I can prevent letters but special characters, like @, keep being inserted. Why am I getting a reference error?

```js
// I have two functions 
function formatarCPF(event, controle) {
    //this line check the returned value from the functions defined below
    var eNumero = permitirApenasNumeros(event.keyCode);

    if (!eNumero)
        event.preventDefault();

    if (event.keyCode != 8) {
        var valor = controle.value;

        if (valor.length == 3) {
            controle.value = (controle.value + ".");
        }

        if (valor.length == 7) {
            controle.value = (controle.value + ".");
        }

        if (valor.length == 11) {
            controle.value = (controle.value + "-");
        }
    }
}

if(event.keyCode != 8) {
    var valor = controle.value;

    if (valor.length == 0) {
        controle.value = "(";
    }

    if(valor.length == 2) {
        controle.value = (controle.value +  String.fromCharCode(event.which)  + ")");
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if (valor.length == 9) {
        controle.value = (controle.value + "-");
    }
}

function permitirApenasNumeros(code) {
    //checks to see if the user typed a number
    var regex = /[0-9]/;

        if(regex.test(String.fromCharCode(code)) || code == 8) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
    <label for="tbCPF">CPF:</label>
    <input  onkeydown="formatarCPF(event, this)" maxlength="14" placeholder="___.___.___-__"  />
</div>
```

Comment: That's not how you use event listeners. Just replace `onkeydown="formatarCPF(event, this)"` with `onkeydown="formatarCPF"`.

Comment: Did you physically go out your way to format your code so bad.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code formatting has many issues that make it nearly impossible to read, but it seems to me that the problem is your second `if(event.keyCode != 8) {` block that is outside the `formatarCPF` event listener. Since it is outside, the `event` variable isn't defined.

If you format your code properly this would be super trivial to catch. You can use tools like [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to do it for you if you prefer.

Comment: I receive critics about my formatting all the time. I will try to improve it.

Answer (score 5):

Try HTML5

```
<input type="number" />
```

Or regex

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]*$" />
```

Comment: One can use below solution as well. Jsfiddle.net/Lm2hS/

Answer (score 1):

To allow only `numbers` inside an `HTML Input Element` just set its `type` to `number`

```html
<input min='0' type="number">
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply scrap all that JavaScript and use:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work
 HTML

```
 <input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="extra7" name="extra7" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 function isNumber(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```